# I want to provide my ASP MVC Application on my Server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, networking, iis-express

i have ASP MVC 4 application, i want to provide or Hosting into my local Windows 7 Server with IIS8. I don't know how. I need help.
Thanks!

Comment: (1) Setup your [server](http://www.iis.net/learn) (2) Setup your network. If it gets too complicated, host your site with a provider.

Comment: This has everything to do with networking and nothing to do with MVC or ASP. THis might need to be migrated to a more suitable site once you have provided more specific explanation of your problem.